# How can I run OS X on a virtual machine in OS X? (Use case: testing software on different OS versions.)

Tags: macos, virtualization

I'm currently running OS X 10.8.5 and I would like to set up a virtual machine that runs OS X 10.9. (The other way around would be fine too. I would upgrade to OS X 10.9 and run OS X 10.8.5 in a virtual machine.)

**Use case:** I'm a Mac developer and I would like to test my mac app on different operating systems versions. If I would develop my app on OS X 10.9 there would be no way to know if the app runs well on OS X 10.8.

Do you know any tool that accomplishes that? It shouldn't be a licensing problem, because I have already "bought" licenses for OS X 10.6, 10.8, 10.9 and 10.10-beta2.

### What I tried so far...

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/q/119308/199544) which basically asks the same thing, but I think its not a duplicate, because that question is from 2010, things probably have changed since then, and this question is not about OS X 10.5 or 10.6. (At the time of this writing we have 2014.)

Another option would be to install to a separate partition on an external hard drive, but that's less flexible than a virtual machine.

### Other acceptable solutions

For me, using a virtual machine is optional. I'm really just searching for the easiest process to verify wether my software runs smoothly on different OS versions, so other solutions - not based on virtualization - are welcome too!

Comment: I removed the outdated question. Did you *try* virtualizing it already?

Comment: @slhck well, no, I don't know where to start. I have VMWare 5 installed on my computer and I can set up a virtual machine there and run an install program from an install CD (or an ISO-image of one). But for current OSX versions there are no install images, just an "Install OS X 10.10 Beta 2 Developer Preview.app" or similar. I have a WindowsXP CD, so I can install WinXP on a VM. Don't know how to create a VM without installation media...

Comment: Seems to be a dupe of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106476/how-to-install-osx-mavericks-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

[Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) allows you to you run Lion (10.7) and Mountain Lion (10.8) as a guest inside a Mavericks (10.9) host.

Comment: and how do I do this? Is there any tutorial describing it? I searched, and the only thing I could find was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NavbZoV7P7U) that describes how to install exactly the same version of the OS that is currently present in the "recovery partition". So, I could install OS X 10.8 into a VM now, then upgrade to OS X 10.9 and keep using the OS X 10.8 VM... Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: Parallels has documentation on their website and forums, it is very simple. You re-download older versions of OS X from the App Store or use a USB installer, and when you create a new virtual machine you simply choose that as the source to install the OS. http://kb.parallels.com/en/112121

Comment: I've done the exact same thing with Fusion.  It's not hypervisor specific. It's more about what resources your host has to share and what you dedicate to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the Yosemite beta today on my Mavericks laptop using VMware Fusion 6.  It was simple and straightforward and I even used the wizards to setup the VM.  But this doesn't always work...the Developer's Preview wouldn't get past the Install OS X screen.

[image: screenshot of 10.9 & 10/10 side by side]

Comment: I did that too. I think you can get past the install screen. Just give it an extra hour of time ;) There are some problems though: 1) The transparency is not working. In your screenshot you see that the menu bar is white. In real OSX Yosemite, the menu bar is semi-transparent. 2) Everything is really slow. When you move some window around, you have something like 2 frames per second or worse (and I have a Core i7 with 2 cores for the VM and a dedicated 1GB graphics card plus internal graphics.) Restarting takes 15min. It's really unusable

Comment: For OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), it's reasonable fast though.